# jQuery remove parent div if contains integer

Tags: jquery, dom

I have the following situation, I'm trying to find div's with a certain integer and then remove it's containing parent div if found.

```
<div id="top_container">
   <div class="img_id">0</div>
</div>

<script>
$('#button').click(function(){
    $(".img_id:contains(0)").closest("div").remove();
});
</script>
```

But for some reason, this only removes the div with class `img_id` but doesn't remove it's parent div. My question is, how do I remove it's parent div after finding the correct integer value?

Comment: Don't you hate it when the answer to your question is in your question title? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) will return self or the closest element in the ancestor tree, so you can use [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) in this situation

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the
>   selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its
>   ancestors in the DOM tree.

Try

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $(".img_id:contains(0)").parent("div").remove();
});
```

---

Also using [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector) may not be the best idea since it will return true of the value is 10, I mostly prefers to use a manual filter like

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    $(".img_id").filter(function () {
        return $.trim($(this).text()) == 0
    }).parent("div").remove();
});
```

Comment: This seems to remove 0 but if I set the value to 10, the filter doesn't seem to remove the div with value 10

Comment: @mplungjan as we all know that is not how it works here... so we can just ignore it

Comment: @user2028856 can you recreate the case in http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cw3yM/1/ - have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cw3yM/2/

Comment: and also thanks a lot for the filter suggestion, prevented the issue from happening in the future!  :)

Comment: The `.filter(...)` example will remove empty divs as well.

Answer (score 0):

[`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) selects the first element that matches the selector, up from the DOM tree while [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) selects all the elements that are parent of another element in the DOM tree.

Use [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/):

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $(".img_id:contains(0)").parent("div").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove parent using `parent` like this:

```
$(".img_id:contains(0)").parent("div").remove();
```

`closest` get self div as it is most closest.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a6NJk/658/